# Reloading the page with the post data

Tags: javascript

I have tried to find on the stackoverflow before asking but the answers, I have found, haven't resolved my problem.

The page I am working on sends the post request. On the click of the button, I have to reload the page with the same post request. 
Currently I am using

```
this.parent.location.reload();
```

But it is sending a Get request. I have also tried

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

But it is also not working.

Please suggest a way to reload the page with the same post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have server-side access, (which I assume you do), you could populate a hidden HTML form with the server side values, have the method of the form set to `POST`, and then send the form in JavaScript (with a [`submit()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method). That will reload the page and maintain the POST values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the POST request is generated by a button which is from different API and the data it is sending to the server side is very huge. For sending the reload request, its sending from the popup. I will try to implement this solution and let you know. :)